# Port 8080 and 22 Redirect 2222 doesnt work

Tags: centos, iptables

I am attempting to open a few ports 8080 and 22 redirecting to 2222. I have selinux disabled in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`.

I am using 8080 to access Tomcat and Port 22 to have it redirect to 2222. When I use the following commands:

```
[root@tomcat7test bin]# iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
[root@tomcat7test bin]# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2222
```

And then restart iptables, I cannot access my webpage http://localhost:8080/

When I run netstat, I see the ports are opened:

```
[root@tomcat7test ~]$ netstat -an | grep '22'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9922   private/smtp
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3848226 /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3848225
[rkahil@tomcat7test ~]$ netstat -an | grep '8080'
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN
```

I always get: This page cannot be displayed on the web browser. Does anyone have any suggestions I can do to make the webpage more accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add ESTABLISHED to my iptables rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://askubuntu.com/questions/444729/redirect-port-80-to-8080-and-make-it-work-on-local-machine :

loopback traffic doesn't pass from PREROUTING but only from OUTPUT.

so you should add:

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2222`